# Unalignable boolean Series key provided

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, slice

I keep running into this problem when trying to take a slice of a pandas DataFrame.  It has four columns as shown below and we'll call it `all_data`:

[image]

I can plot it nicely with the code below:

```
generations = ['Boomers+', 'Gen X', 'Millennials', 'Students', 'Gen Z']

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))

for i,generations in enumerate(generations):
    ax = plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
    ix = all_data['CustomerGroups'] == generations

    kmf.fit(T[ix], C[ix], label=generations)


    kmf.plot(ax=ax, legend=False)
    plt.title(generations, size = 16)
    plt.xlabel('Timeline in years')
    plt.xlim(0,5)
    if  i ==0:
        plt.ylabel('Frac Remaining After $n$ Yrs')
    if  i ==3:
        plt.ylabel('Frac Remaining After $n$ Yrs')

fig.tight_layout()
#fig.suptitle('Survivability of Checking Accts By Generation', size = 16)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.88, hspace = .4)
plt.show()
```

However, I would like to do a couple of things that seem similar.  The `CustomerGroups` column has `NaN` in it which is the reason for the manual array of `generations`.

It seems like every operation to slice the dataframe and remove the NaN gives me an error `Unalignable boolean Series key provided` when I attempt to plot is using the same code and just changing the dataframe.

Likewise, the `Channel` column can be either `Online` or `Branch`.  Again, any way I try to split the `all_data` either by the `Channel` column to create new dataframes from either `Online` or `Branch` criteria, I get the same error regarding a boolean index.

I have tried many options from other posts here `(reset_index, pd.notnull,)` etc. , but it keeps creating the index problem when I go to plot it with the same code.

What is the best method to create subsets from the `all_data` that does not created the `Unalignable boolean Series key` error?

This worked in the past:

```
#create the slice using the .copy
online = checkingRed[['Channel', 'State', 'CustYears', 'Observed',
'CustomerGroups', 'ProductYears']].copy()

#remove the branch from the data set
online = online.loc[online['Channel'] != 'Branch'] #use .loc for cleaner slice

#reset the index so that it is unique
online['index'] = np.arange(len(online))
online = online.set_index('index')
```

Comment: `online['index'] = np.arange(len(online))` here `len(online)` returns the number or len of the number of columns, you want `online['index'] = np.arange(online.shape[0])`

Comment: This may or may not be related to your issue because I know nothing about *pandas* and your indentation is broken. The `for i,generations in enumerate(generations):` line looks problematic because after that for-loop, _generations_ will refer to the last item from the original _generations_ list.

Comment: oops, just noticed that.  Thanks, but that's not the issue since the code works perfectly on a dataframe before any slicing is done.

Comment: I made the change @EdChum and I still get the error.  I am using Pandas v 0.18.1 if that matters.  With the code above, the result of `online.index.is_unique` returns `True`.

Comment: I'd have to have your actual data and complete code to fully debug this

Comment: I am just loading in the dataframe above. Then plotting it with the code and it makes a plot for each generation.  I then want to filter the dataframe on `Channel` by `OnlinePhone` or `Branch`, then re-run the plotting one both of the slices.  The original plot works great, but every attempt to slice the dataframe into  `Online` or `Branch` yields the error when it runs the `kmf.fit(T[ix], C[ix], label=generations)` step.  This appears due to boolean key error as the result of filtering.